# jquery calculations. Multiple div totals and grand total calc

Tags: javascript, jquery, calc

Im trying to calculate the price * input value for multiple div's but not sure how to do it (with .each()???) .

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V5hrY/2/

You can see I commented the part that is not working correctly with this:

```
>//HAVING TROUBLE HERE!!!
$('.total p span').each(function(){
        $(this).html(
            $('.total p span').closest(".info").find('.price p span').html() 
            * 
            $('.total p span').closest(".info").find('.ticket input').val());
    });
```

Most parts are working well except when you have a few integers in different input fields and choose a different radio button, then the individual calculations are off. Particularly because I have very limited knowledge of .each() or looping while calculating specific things to a specific total in each div.

Let me know if that wasnt clear, its basically the `.each()` right under `//HAVING TROUBLE HERE.`

Also, if anyone could also speculate this answer for me. I could not reproduce this bug for some reason on the fiddle, but this is one other bug I get on my site. On initial page load, if I do not choose anything on the radio button and choose a value on either the second or third `ul`... the grand total returns total `$NaN` until I click into all the input fields, then it starts calculating correctly.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Thanks Amin, still trying to get better at editing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is the following:

```
        $('.total p span').each(function(){
            $(this).html(
                $(this).closest(".info").find('.price p span').html() 
                * 
                $(this).closest(".info").find('.ticket input').val());
        });
```

The way you had it changed the inner html for all of these span tags on each iteration - with the result that ALL got updated with the sum calculated for the LAST element.

Comment: Beat me to it! Important to distinguish what you call inside a loop or a function attached to an element. Generally each() functions will loop through each item (obviously) so the $(this) becomes the right call for individual items being looped upon.

Comment: wow thanks! I can't believe I was on the right track lol. Thought it would have been something completely different. Thank you both for the explanation too that totally makes sense. Do you have any idea about the NaN issue? I was going to edit my original post because I just tested it again and its whenever I click ANY input before doing anything else... until I either click the radio button or click into all three inputs then it will calculate, until then it shows NaN in the grand total...

Comment: sorry - that part i could not reproduce.